# Selecting next div with Button and changing the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 4 `div` elements each with their own value, for example `0`. I have a button with a plus and minus that changes the value in each box. I also have a set next button so you can do the same thing to the next box.

The problem I'm facing is how to select the next `div` and change the value with the same plus and minus buttons and then selecting the next `div` and doing the same until you're at the end. It then has to return to the first `div`. Here is my code:

```
<div class="code_div">
    <div class="code_area">
        <p id="number1">00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="code_area2">
        <p id="number2">00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="code_area3">
        <p id="number3">00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="code_area4">
        <p id="number4">00</p>
    </div>
```

```js
var value = 0;
var plus = false;
var minus = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#set_next').click(function() {
    });

    $('#minus').click(function() {
        minus = false;
        plus = true;
        if (plus == true) {
            value -= 5;
        }
        displayValue()
    });

    $('#plus').click(function() {
        minus = true;
        plus = false;
        if (minus == true) {
            value += 5;
        }
        displayValue() 
    });
});

function displayValue() {
    document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = value;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where are the plus and minus buttons? Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)

Comment: sorry there they are... ill try to create a js fiddle quicly

Comment: <button id="plus" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">plus</button>
<button id="set_next" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Set Next</button>
<button id="minus" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">minus</button>

Comment: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/z4ukhvt4/)

Comment: i dont know why my plus and minus doesnt work on jsfiddle but on my machine it works fine

Comment: @JulianFaul, I just added a simple solution using your original HTML, at the bottom of my post answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var value = 0;
var plus = false;
var minus = false;
var index=1;
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#set_next').click(function() {
index++;
//update
$("#number"+index).css("color","blue");
if(index==5){
index=1;
}
});

 $('#minus').click(function() {
       minus = false;
       plus = true;
        if (plus == true){
        value -= 5;
    }
displayValue()
    });

 $('#plus').click(function() {
       minus = true;
       plus = false;
    if (minus == true){
         value += 5;
    }
displayValue() 
    });
});

function displayValue(){
        document.getElementById("number"+index).innerHTML = value;
}
```

Comment: Yes that works, i have been trying other things with .next i think i made it to complicated for myself... but this is works 100%. Thank you so much for the help. Now i will be able to do it next time..

Comment: how would you go about to highlight the one that is selected just making the font color blue

Comment: @JulianFaul you are welcome dude, please chech the update in the click function ,, you would achieve that with jquery

Answer (score 5):

Keep it simple. You have a list of divs, so use a [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) instead. Even if you want to keep your original markup, this should give an idea on how to implement this.

```js
var $items = $('ul li'),
    qtItems = $items.length,
    activeItem = 0;

$('#setnext').click(function () {
  $items.removeClass('active').eq(++activeItem % qtItems).addClass('active');
});
                   
$('#plus, #minus').click(function () {
  var currvalue = $items.eq(activeItem % qtItems).text();
  this.id === 'plus' ? currvalue++ : currvalue--;
  $items.eq(activeItem % qtItems).text(currvalue);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: .5;
}

li.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
</ul>

<button id="setnext">set next</button>
<button id="plus">plus</button>
<button id="minus">minus</button>
```

But, if you cannot simplify your markup, here is another [simple solution](http://jsfiddle.net/3v00mfzd/1/) using your original html.
As you can see, you don't need all of those classes and ids.

Comment: The part that is really elegant is `.eq(++activeItem % qtItems)`, a nice way of tracking the element in focus. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Although your code needs a lot of polishing (i can give you a cleaner approach if you want)
https://jsfiddle.net/cbw4zc55/
something along these lines?
html code:

```
<div class="code_div">
<div class="code_area">
<p id="number1">00</p>
</div>
<div class="code_area2">
<p id="number2">00</p>
</div>
<div class="code_area3">
<p id="number3">00</p>
</div>
<div class="code_area4">
<p id="number4">00</p>
</div>
    <button id="set_next">set next</button>
    <button id="minus">minus</button>
    <button id="plus">plus</button>
```

javascript:

```
var current = 1;
    var max = 4;

    var value = 0;
    var plus = false;
    var minus = false;
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#set_next').click(function() {
        if( current < max )
        {
            current+=1;
        }
        else
        {
            current = 1;
        }
     value = parseInt($("#number"+current).text());
    });

     $('#minus').click(function() {

           minus = false;
           plus = true;
            if (plus == true){
            value -= 5;
        }

    displayValue()

        });


     $('#plus').click(function() {

           minus = true;
           plus = false;
        if (minus == true){
             value += 5;
        }
    displayValue() 

        });

    });


    function displayValue(){

            document.getElementById("number"+current).innerHTML = value;

    }
```

EDIT:
Note that you would need to recalculate the current element value each time you change your focus to a new one (aside from that the selected answer is just perfect as well)

Comment: this is amazing.. im still new to this so i dont understand 100% what is happening.. ill go look up parse int.. also how would you change the color of the number that active?? i would try to add css to the ('set_next') click function adding and removing class .active with properties (color:blue).

Comment: if you could just point me in the right direction ill figure it out myself

Comment: $("#number"+current).closest("div").toggleClass("myactiveclass");
to get the closest div from your current element (you could have lets say code_area class for all elements instead of code_area1 etc and do .closest(".code_area")
And toggleClass will remove a class if exists, or add if it doesnt , so call your toggle class on your set_next before and after changing your current element, to remove class from your previous and add to your current. Then add css to the class and you are done :)

Comment: This way you will add a class to the wrapper element which will allow you to style it accordingly. If you would prefer to target the actuall element skip the .closest part

Comment: Awesome thank you so much for the help.. also thanks to everybody who helped aswel